# Access object members from Instance ID

Tags: gml, game-maker

I'm getting the Instance ID of an object from `collision_line()`

Now that I have this instance, I want to get it's `image_angle`, but I get an *'unknown variable'* message when I try that.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what is the **value** of this collision_line()? The `collision_line()` function returns an instance id - however when nothing is found it returns `noone` (`-4`).. So you'll have to test for that first:

```
var inst, imgangle;
inst = collision_line(...);
if (inst != noone) {
    imgangle = inst.image_angle;
    //etc etc
}
```

or alternativelly (more cleanly in GM), we can "abuse" the `with` statement. With executes all following code from the perspective of the given instance id (or for all instances of a certain object when given the object id).
However the value `noone` will automatically prevent any execution.

```
var inst, imgangle;
inst = collision_line(...);
with (inst) {
    imgangle = image_angle; 
    //note that we do no longer have to put "inst." before getting a variable
    //etc etc
}
```

Comment: IMO, using `with()` in this way is perfectly sensible and not an abuse of accidental behaviour. You're running the code on whatever instance has been found - if none has been found, you don't run the code.

Comment: I had discovered the solution in that time, but thanks for taking the time to answer :)